# If you know the current page, and total page count, how to mimick paging like google?

Tags: c#

Having a tough time figuring out the start and end for my loop.

I am looping and generating links for pages for a pager.

No matter what page the user is on, I want to show 10 links BEFORE and AFTER the current page.

just like google does.

**I need help calculating the start and end for this loop.**

Comment: please post your code attempt...

Comment: Do you always want to show (up to) the 10 pages preceeding and (up to) 10 pages following the current page, or do you want to always show (up to) 21 pages?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = Math.Max(pageNum - 10, 1); i <= Math.Min(pageNum + 10, maxPage); ++i)
  WritePageLink(i);
```